# pytorch : How to stack 2 tensors

Tags: python, stack, pytorch, concatenation, tensor

I’m trying to stack 2 tensors `A.shape=(64,16,16)` and `B.shape=(64,16,16)` in a tensor of shape `C.shape=(1,128,16,16)`

and non of functions I’ve tried work where
`torch.stack` => `C.shape=(2,64,16,16)` and
`torch.cat` => `C.shape=(128,16,16)`

can enyones help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat first and then use [`unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html#torch.unsqueeze) to add singleton dimension at `0th` position

```
torch.cat([A, B]).unsqueeze(0)
```